# is there a way to verify if a word exists in determined idiom?

Tags: idioms, words, aspell

I have some word lists that was extracted from aspell dictionary.

The problem is that some of the words that aspell returns isn't valid words.

I'd like know if there are a way to check if the words returned exists in determined idiom or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could validate them using [google spelling api](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-spelling-java/).

Comment: I'm trying to use your sugestion but without success.

On English language it works fine, but in another language 
like Portuguese ou Italian I don't have success.

Have you ever used the api with another language? or you have 
another suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: I have fixed the bug and create a little app to help in my job. Thanks.